Does Arizona Proposition 133 [2024] just ban ranked choice voting?
Does Arizona Proposition 133 [2024] just ban ranked choice voting? Does it do anything else?

Ballotpedia explains Arizona Amendment 133 (in 2024) as follows:

A "yes" vote supports this constitutional amendment to:

require partisan primary elections for partisan offices;

prohibit primary elections where all candidates, regardless of political party affiliation, run in the same primary election, such as
top-two, top-four, and top-five primaries;

provide that the state's direct primary election law supersedes local charters and ordinances that are inconsistent with that law.


A "no" vote opposes amending the Arizona Constitution to require
partisan primary elections for partisan offices, maintaining the
status quo of requiring partisan primaries by state statute.

It bans "jungle primaries" but the amendment doesn't directly address ranked choice voting in the general election.

It seems like ranked choice voting in the primary would also be allowed. As an example the Republican 2016 Presidential Primary with how many candidates jumped in would be a case for ranked choice in the primary.

Note that neighboring California uses jungle primaries
